# Android Emulator - JumpTap Ads returning error 404

Tags: android, android-emulator, ads

I'm using JumpTap in my project to display banner ads.

The Ads have been approved at their portal for my application but still if it try to run the project in emulator, in the logcat,

I see error like JAdFetcher.getContent - Received error[404]

Is there anything that can be checked to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You will get a 404 if the publisher, site or spot that is passed in the call to Jumptap's server is invalid.  If you send me a note I'll work with you to get everything verified and on the road to get ads back.

Disclaimer: I am representative of Jumptap.